# Selecting children of an object

Tags: jquery

I have this reqular ul > li structure

```
<ul class='compare'>
    <li>Level 1
        <ul>
            <li>Level 2</li>
            <li>Level 2</li>
            <li>Level 2</li>
            <li>Level 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Level 1
        <ul>
            <li>Level 2</li>
            <li>Level 2</li>
            <li>Level 2</li>
            <li>Level 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Level 1
        <ul>
            <li>Level 2</li>
            <li>Level 2</li>
            <li>Level 2</li>
            <li>Level 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I use `$("ul.compare > li").live(...);` to assign mouse events to children of ul

But now I need to get children of an object. Let say `obj` is my `$("ul.compare")`

If I do like this `$("li", obj).live(...)` this assigns event to all li not only children.

I can do in this way but I don't like it

```
obj.children("li").each(function () {
    $(this).live(...);
});
```

Is there a way to select all children of an object and apply `live` directly without using `.each()`?

Comment: ... what are you trying to do? What's wrong with `$("ul.compare > li").live(...);`? Also note that as of jQuery 1.7, `live()` has been depreciated in favour of [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on).

Comment: Thanks for live() warning. I'm trying to write my first plugin and I have only this `return this.each(function() {var o = options;var obj = $(this); ...});` so selector can be an id or a classname when this plugin applied. Before there was `.selector` but now it's gone.

Comment: I'm having difficulties determining what you want the new solution to be.  Do you want a event to fire on any `li` in the `ul.compare` or something else?  Is `obj` a selector being passed in?

Comment: @Eric check my answer below, that's what I was try to do but I wasn't aware of `.on()` and it's capabilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Matt, it seems you answered my question with your comment unwittingly. Solution is `.on()`

While this is not working, and we have to use `.each()` to assign `mouseover` to every matched element

```
//obj.children("li").children("ul").children("li").live("mouseover", function () {...}); //Does not work
obj.children("li").children("ul").children("li").each(function () {
    $(this).live("mouseover", function () {...});
});
```

this works and there is no need `.each()`

```
obj.children("li").children("ul").children("li").on("mouseover", function () {...});
```